# How to connect a motor with a 4mm shaft to a propeller that takes 1/2 inch shaft?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors

I have a motor with a 4mm shaft. I've purchased a propeller that's designed to fit a 1/2 inch shaft. How can I securely couple the two?

Comment: Have you asked yourself if attaching something designed for a 1/2 inch shaft with all the weight and strength requirements that implies is a sensible thing to attach to a motor with a 4mm shaft, with all the (lack of) strength which *that* implies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the motor speed matches the speed range needed for the prop, then make an adapter with relevant locking screws or equivalent, balanced as necessary.

something like :

[image]

Source https://shaft-collars-couplings.staffordmfg.com/viewitems/shaft-adapter-couplings/shaft-adapter-couplings---step-up-type-with-keyway

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I'm kind of a neophyte here.

Comment: @Megalonychidae see update

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very, very much.

Answer (score 4):

Following on from Solar Mike's answer, I'm not sure you'll be able to find something off-the-shelf with the diameters you have (mix of imperial and metric units), so you may need to get something custom made instead. I have sketched the following (not knowing what shaft lengths you had, I made a few assumptions - adjust to suit your needs):

[image]

The outer diameter is 1/2 inch, while the ID is 4mm. I have toleranced it as H7 hole so that it's a snug fit on the 4mm shaft. The adapter is secured onto the 4mm shaft with 2 M3 grub screws at 90 degrees, you can also use Loctite 638 if you want to be sure. I have added a 1mm chamfer on the end of the shaft adapter.

Comment: Good job, plus 1.

Comment: Beautiful sketches, do you mind if I ask what software you used?

Comment: Thanks. I used Autodesk Inventor.

Answer (score 0):

Use gears, mechanical losses will only be 1 % and that's negligible.